# Get single dimensional php array from model getData

Tags: php, model, array

From my model collection I got the list of data, which is in format - `array(0 => "first", "1" => "second", ...)`. Is it possible to get the data in a normal single dimensional php array like `array("first", "second", ...).`

Comment: `array("a","b","c")` is what you write in PHP. `array(0 => "a", 1 => "b", 2 => "c")` is what it looks like from a PHP perspective ...